# Convert text to input, allow edit, and then allow reset back to text with original value

Tags: javascript, jquery, input

I'm looking to create a table with normal text, with a button or icon next to said text, which when clicked turns the text into an input box, and turns the button, or icon into a reset button/icon. Once this is pressed, the value returns to the initial value as plain text.

I have the following code to do the conversion between text and input:

https://jsfiddle.net/n23pjLma/

```
      <table id="container">
            <tr><th>Tabular Data</th></tr>
            <tr style="height:50px">
            <td><input class="form-control" type="text" value="Test 1" /></td>

            <td><button class="btn btn-danger">Edit</button> <button class="btn btn-success">Reset</button></td>
        </tr>
        <tr style="height:50px">
            <td><input class="form-control" type="text" value="Test 1" /></td>
            <td><button class="btn btn-danger">Edit</button> <button class="btn btn-success">Reset</button></td>
        </tr>
       <tr style="height:50px">
            <td><input class="form-control" type="text" value="Test 1" /></td>
            <td><button class="btn btn-danger">Edit</button> <button class="btn btn-success">Reset</button></td>
        </tr>
    </table>

        <script> function setupRows(context) {
  $("span.view", context).remove();
  $('input', context).each(function() {
    $("<span />", { text: this.value, "class":"view" }).insertAfter(this);
    $(this).hide();
  });
}
setupRows('#container');

        $("button").toggle(function() {
        $(this).closest("tr").find("input, span.view").toggle();
        }, function() {
           setupRows($(this).closest("tr"));
        });
   </script>
```

What I've been struggling with is having one button (rather than two) at any given time, and then switching back to the default value as normal text.

Any ideas?

Comment: do you want to edit one cell at time or entire row?

Comment: One cell at a time - I also need to be able to use an icon/image as the button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi does this help at all?   I added a "data" element to the form input and using addClass and removeClass to keep track of the button state....

(The CSS is just to add and remove border on the input box when active/readonly)

[JS FIDDLE v4](http://jsfiddle.net/incept0/gnobdLxv/4/)

```
  input {
      border: none;
  }
  .editButton {
      border: solid 1px #000;
  }

  <table id="container">
            <tr><th>Tabular Data</th></tr>
            <tr style="height:50px">
            <td><input class="form-control" data-default-value="Test 1" type="text" value="Test 1" readonly /></td>
            <td><button class="btn btn-danger">Edit</button></td>
        </tr>
        <tr style="height:50px">
            <td><input class="form-control" data-default-value="Test 2" type="text" value="Test 2" readonly /></td>
            <td><button class="btn btn-danger">Edit</button></td>
        </tr>
        <tr style="height:50px">
            <td><input data-default-value="Test 3" class="form-control" type="text" value="Test 3" readonly /></td>
            <td><button class="btn btn-danger">Edit</button></td>
        </tr>
    </table>

   (function($){

       $(function(){  //document.ready

           $(".btn").on('click', function() {
               if ($(this).hasClass('editButton')) {
                   $(this).removeClass('editButton');
                   $(this).html('Edit');
                   $(this).closest('tr').find('input').prop('readonly', true);
                   var defaultValue = $(this).closest('tr').find('input').data(this, 'default-value');
                   $(this).closest('tr').find('input').val(defaultValue[0].defaultValue);
               } else {
                   $(this).addClass('editButton');
                   $(this).html('Reset');
                   $(this).closest('tr').find('input').prop('readonly', false);
                   $(this).closest('tr').find('input').select().focus();
               }
           });
       });

    })(jQuery);
```

Comment: This was the closest to what I needed. Fantastic work. To illustrate what I meant by the icons, I've added the following:

https://jsfiddle.net/qfd64soL/

Comment: Thanks.  Glad it helped.  I see what you mean on the icons.  Looks like you got that figured out.  Looks great.  :)

Comment: Thanks! Yeah, I can do the html and the styling fine, it's just javascript that I stumble over sometimes!

Answer (score 0):

Try this, add class `reset` to Edit button and write the script as:

**SCRIPT:**

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $("button").on("click", function(){
       if($(this).hasClass("reset")) {
         var val1=$(this).closest("td").siblings("td").find("input").val();
         if(val1!="") {
            $(this).closest("td").siblings("td").find("input").replaceWith(val1);
            $(this).text("Edit");
            $(this).removeClass("reset");
            $(this).removeClass("edit");       
         }
       }
       else {
           var val1=$(this).closest("td").siblings("td").text();      $(this).closest("td").siblings("td").empty().append("<input/>").find("input").val(val1);
           $(this).removeClass("edit"); 
           $(this).addClass("reset");       
           $(this).text("Reset")

       }
     });
});
```

**HTML:**

```
<table id="container">
            <tr><th>Tabular Data</th></tr>
            <tr style="height:50px">
            <td><input class="form-control" type="text" value="Test 1" /></td>

            <td><button class="btn btn-danger reset">Reset</button> </td>
        </tr>
        <tr style="height:50px">
            <td><input class="form-control" type="text" value="Test 1" /></td>
            <td><button class="btn btn-danger reset">Reset</button> </td>
        </tr>
       <tr style="height:50px">
            <td><input class="form-control" type="text" value="Test 1" /></td>
            <td><button class="btn btn-danger reset">Reset</button> </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/NCHJB/462/)

Answer (score 0):

You must to save the old values when an edit action is performed.

Please take a look at my solution
[JSFiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/vasilenicusor/g1vLf6b0/1/)

**HTML**

```
<table id="container">
    <tr><th>Column 1</th><th>Column 2</th></tr>
    <tr>
        <td id="col_1_1">Test 1-1</td>
        <td id="col_1_2">Test 1-2</td>
        <td id="actions_1"><button line="1" class="btn btn-danger">Edit</button></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td id="col_2_1">Test 2-1</td>
        <td id="col_2_2">Test 2-2</td>
        <td id="actions_2"><button line="1" class="btn btn-danger">Edit</button></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td id="col_3_1">Test 3-1</td>
        <td id="col_3_2">Test 3-2</td>
        <td id="actions_3"><button line="1" class="btn btn-danger">Edit</button></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

**Script**

```
var old_values = {},
    num_cols = 2,
    line_data = {},
    i;

$("#container").on('click',"button",function(){
    var current_line = $(this).attr('line');
    if($(this).text() == 'Edit'){
        for(i=1;i<=num_cols;i++){
            line_data[i]=$("#col_"+current_line+"_"+i).html();
            $("#col_"+current_line+"_"+i).html('<input type="text" id="col_'+current_line+'_'+i+'_input" value="'+line_data[i]+'" class="form-control" />');
        }
        old_values[current_line] = line_data;
        $('#actions_'+current_line).html('<button line="'+current_line+'" class="btn btn-success">Save</button><button line="'+current_line+'" class="btn btn-default">Reset</button>');
    }
    else if ($(this).text() == 'Save'){
        // save data
        for(i=1;i<=num_cols;i++){

            $("#col_"+current_line+"_"+i).html($("#col_"+current_line+"_"+i+"_input").val());
        }
        $('#actions_'+current_line).html('<button line="'+current_line+'" class="btn btn-danger">Edit</button>');

    }
    else
    {
        for(i=1;i<=num_cols;i++){

            $("#col_"+current_line+"_"+i).html(old_values[current_line][i]);
        }
        $('#actions_'+current_line).html('<button line="'+current_line+'" class="btn btn-danger">Edit</button>');
    }
});
```

Comment: This is so much messier than my solution, why would you even post this 30 minutes later after seeing my answer. ??

Comment: I have posted the solution because was already done before see your answer. Is not an elegant solution, i know that, and don't ask me why i have posted this example and not other more "beauty". The context of the problem is not complete